# WPF DataGrid: How do you set the style of the first row only?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, row, selectedindex

I've tried searching for the answer, but the question that's been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498375/style-first-row-in-a-wpf-datagrid) has not been answered.

I've tried some complicated XAML, but it's never worked. The code below grays out *all* rows if the first row is selected. I need to gray out the first row only, regardless of which row index is selected.

```
<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Value="0"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

Would anyone be able to help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `AlternationCount` property found on all `ItemsControls` (ref [ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159470/how-to-have-first-item-bolded-in-listbox/38159710#38159710)).

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          AlternationCount="2147483647"
          ... 
          >
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

**EDIT**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          AlternationCount="2"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
          ... 
          >
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                </Trigger>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=PreviousData}}"
                    Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works, except for one small issue: I need the AlternationCount to be equal to 2 (to have alternating white and gray row backgrounds). If I set the AlternationCount to this Int.MaxValue I lose the background coloring. Any suggestions to have both features working?

Comment: Sure, but it requires [IsVirtualizing="False"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171955/how-to-set-color-for-first-row-in-datagrid#comment44741291_28175517), that's why I prefer the first method.

Comment: Thank you again. I think we're really close. I'll give it some more time to see how it pans out.